# Is there a shortcut in IntelliJ to import a class from a different package (than already imported)?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, import, package, keyboard-shortcuts

I enable auto-importing unambiguous keywords and also use <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to resolve ambiguities.

Sometimes though I type an already-imported keyword, and want it to be an import of the same name but from a different package. So I'm looking for a shortcut like <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> (which I already tried) that says: "Import class from another package..."

I realize it would have to be fully qualified (e.g. com.foo.bar.class), and that's fine. It would just save me from having to copy/paste the fully qualified class every time. This occurs for example when writing mappers between an AutoValue POJO *and* a DAO object with a logically similar name, or said POJO *and* a generated protobuf message class in a wire-to-UI service implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IntelliJ IDEA we can import a class from another package on a fly without any shortcuts. Just start typing the class name and choose the necessary package from the appeared popup.

[image]

Comment: Talk about user blindness! Somehow I knew that and didn't know that at the same time. I think because I type the space after a type so quickly and automatically that I've never seen that menu.

Answer (score 0):

@EgorKlepikov helped me see I just needed to not type a space so automatically after I typed the Type, and I'd see a menu.

I still don't see a shortcut for changing the package of just one instance after the fact (i.e. without refactoring all instances in that scope) but thanks to the above I see I can do this at least:

1. Highlight the type.
2. <kbd>→</kbd> to move to end of word.
3. <kbd>Backspace</kbd> and retype the last letter.

Now you can see the menu @Egor's talking about and select a different type, just for that instance.